# Wordpress - getting post meta, best practices

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

I'm using Ajax for displaying posts in popup. I can't find information about true way to getting post meta.

I can get meta field individually:

```
$project_client = get_post_meta( $postId, 'project_client',true );
$project_date = get_post_meta( $postId, 'project_date',true );
$project_place = get_post_meta( $postId, 'project_place',true );
echo $project_client;
```

or to all at once:

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id ); // array of all meta fields 
echo $post_meta['project_client'][0];
```

Which way is right?

Comment: Both are "right". It just depends if you want to get all the data as an array, or as a single variable.

Comment: need to display about ten strings in different parts of template

Comment: Then I would do it all at once to save on loading time

Comment: 2nd one is the best, because it will run the query once, where as the 1st one will query 3 time.

Comment: WP retrieves and caches all the meta values for the post when you first call `get_metadata()` for any key. So you don't increase the number of db queries calling `get_metadata()` per key. Calling it individually also allows the `$single` option, and does `maybe_unserialize()`, even without $single. You might consider the slight php cost if you know nothing is serialized, or the php cost of the function calls, but there should be no db cost. See: `get_metada()` in `wp-incluides/meta.php`.